# Clever can't do a command build in package.json

Tags: adonis.js, clever-cloud

I want to deploy my application Adonis5 js in CLEVER but when i deploy and inspect the logs, i see the server failed because he doesn't run build command (in my case node ace build --production)
when the server start, it search the file server.js but it can't found it because the build command had not be run

Comment: How do you specify the command to build your project `ace build --production` ?

Comment: In package.json

Comment: I mean on Clever Cloud.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the server can't find the build command then this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/71742721/10735807