# node ace build --production, [ error ] "build" command not found error on Digital Ocean Apps

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace, digital-ocean-apps

When trying to configure an application with the following deploy commands:

**Build Command**
`npm run build`
**Run Command**
`node build/server.js`

The following error is thrown:

```
clinica-medica-backend@1.0.0 build
node ace build --production
[ error ]  "build" command not found
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.4.1 -> 8.5.1
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.5.1>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.5.1` to update!
npm notice 
building: exit status 1
ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1

For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
   Node.js: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node

 ! Build failed (145)
```

If you change the build command to:
**Build Command**
`node ace`

```
The following is shown:

Running custom build command: node ace

Available commands
  repl                   Start a new REPL session

db
  db:seed                Execute database seeder files

dump
  dump:rcfile            Dump contents of .adonisrc.json file along with                                 defaults

generate
  generate:key           Generate a new APP_KEY secret
  generate:manifest      Generate ace commands manifest file. Manifest file                              speeds up commands lookup

list
  list:routes            List application routes

make
  make:migration         Make a new migration file
  make:model             Make a new Lucid model
  make:seeder            Make a new Seeder file

migration
  migration:rollback     Rollback migrations to a given batch number
  migration:run          Run pending migrations
  migration:status       Check migrations current status.

Global Flags
  -h, --help boolean     
  -v, --version boolean
```

Without the build command.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exact version you are running on with adonis however the build command you are looking for is in the @adonisjs/assembler package which is installed as a dev dependency by default and I guess when you deploy you set the NODE_ENV environment variable to production by default which when the packages get installed on the server. only the normal dependencies get installed so either add the @adonisjs/assembler to the normal dependencies or you can make the NODE_ENV to be development which I do not recommend